# Buenas, tengo un problema que al seleccionar varias categorias con checkbox en la base de datos solamente se registra 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

Buenas actualmente estoy trabajando en un pequeño blog en php y mysql, lo que pasa es que necesito al crear un nuevo POST o publicación, seleccionar varias categorías del post. Logre crear el sistema de categorías pero al seleccionar varias solamente se muestra 1 en la base de datos.

[image: Imagen 1]

como ven he seleccionado varias categorías pero al revisar la Mysql solamente se ha seleccionado 1 en este caso la categoría Aventura únicamente.

[image: IMAGEN 2]

```
 CODIGO: create.php
    
            <form action="create.php" method="post">
              <div class="input-group">
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="text-input">
              </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Body</label>
                <input type="text" name="body" value="<?php echo $body; ?>" class="text-input">
              </div>
                
              <div class="box">
                    <?php foreach ($categorias as $key => $categoria): ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($topic) && $topic == $topic['id']): ?>
                    
                    
                        <input id="one"  selected value="<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" name="topic_id">
                        <span class="check"></span>
                        <label for="one"><?php echo $categoria['name']; ?></label>                                                
                    <?php else: ?>
                    
                        <input id="one"  selected value="<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" name="topic_id">
                        <span class="check"></span>
                        <label for="one"><?php echo $categoria['name']; ?></label>
                    
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    
    
                    
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
              </div>
```

CODIGO: posts.php

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validatePost.php');

$table = 'posts';
$categorias = selectAll('categorias');

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$title = '';
$body = '';
$topic_id = '';

$posts = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Capitulo creado correctamente';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id'];
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
    $id = $post['id'];
    $title = $post['title'];
    $body = $post['body'];
    $topic = $post['topic_id'];
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Capitulo eliminado correctamente';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Genero actualizado correctamente';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id'];
}
} 
?>
```

Necesito crear que al seleccionar varios checkbox, estos se registren en la base de datos como: topics_id pero la verdad no se como hacerlo, por favor alguien me podría ayudar? y explicarme como solucionarlo porque llevo varios días intentando arreglarlo pero no puedo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado

Una forma en la que puedes recolectar las categorias seleccionadas es agregando los valores a un arreglo, para eso debes cambiar

```
<input id="one"  selected value="<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" name="topic_id">
```

a

```
<input id="one"  selected value="<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" name="topic_id[]">
```

Al poner de esta forma el nombre del input (**topic_id[]**), todos los valores en estado *checked* se almacenaran en la variable con el mismo nombre.

Por lo tanto al momento en que script php procesa los datos, $_POST['topic_id'] seria un array con los valores.

```
$_POST['topic_id'] // array('test','test2')
```

Para guardar este array tienes dos opciones:

1. Si tu diseño de base de datos lo permite, insertar el registro par (id del post e id de la categoría) en la tabla relación de las tablas principales en cuestión (post y categoría tendrian una relación n:m).
2. Si categoria figura como un campo mas en la tabla donde se registran los post, convendría serializar los datos para guardarlos y cuando los necesites los deserializas.

Antes de guardar seria

```
serialize($_POST['topic_id'])
```

y para imprimirlos cuando los recuperes de la base de datos

```
unserialize($_POST['topic_id'])
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no me funciono, agregue: name: "topic_id[]"  pero en la base de datos se marca 0 en topic_id, que puedo hacer para solucionarlo soy nuevo en esto y no se como hacerlo o porque sucede,

Comment: Veo que `create($table, $_POST)` es la función que inserta el registro en la base de datos, podrias mostrar como funciona esa función?? Otra cosa que puedes hacer es sobre escribir la variable `$_POST['topic_id']=serialize($_POST['topic_id']);`  justo antes de llamar la función `create` y cuando quieras mostrarla `$topic = unserialize($post['topic_id']);` despues de la funcion `selectOne`

Comment: Otra cosa el campo `topic_id` en tu base de datos de que tipo es?

Comment: La verdad no se mucho de base de datos, sin embargo creo que el tipo es int(11)

Comment: Si tienes la intención de guardar varios valores en el campo, el tipo int (numero entero) no se servira, es por eso que esta guardando 1 (o sea esta guardando un true porque el valor existe). Para guardar con el serialize tu campo debe ser del tipo string para eso debe ser un varchar,tinytext,mediumtext o el que estimes conveniente por el tamaño que podría tomar tu string.

Comment: Intente cambiándolo a varchat(100) y ahora dice: Array

Comment: Implementaste el serialize en la variable? en la base de datos debe quedar guardado algo asi `a:2:{i:0;s:4:"test";i:1;s:5:"test1";}`

Comment: Cómo agrego serialize en la variable?? O como consigo para ver la base de datos de esa manera, no entiendo mucho como hacerlo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112627/discussion-between-mrvictoxdb-and-ricardo-campos-villarroel).